# What is the best way to display magento website at mobiles as speedily as possible?

Tags: performance, magento, optimization, mobile

I have a magento site and I want to display it on mobiles as speedily as possible with different layout.
ex. tripadvisor.in or amazon.in

Please help me find out the best ways for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: It is about the programming cause I need the way to display DOM Element with mobile display filter using programming way.
I have just define that I am using magento but this is not relates to my this question.

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing in your question that even hints that this is about programming. Please make it clear by articulating what the programming question is and, preferably, by adding code.

Answer (score 0):

I think focusing on media queries is the best way yo do it. If you really need different layouts then you need to define them for your magento design package and just serve a different website code to your mobile visitors by a simple agent detection

Comment: You mean to say that I should design a new one for mobile version.

Is there any other way that will runtime filter the DOM element which I want to display on mobile versions?

Comment: if you are going for that approach you need to modify the css layer which is not hard to do. but it will result in duplication of content which is not a good practice. The parts you need to modify are solely restricted to front end rendering which involves blocks and design layouts.